# Regular expression groups

Tags: regex, regex-group

For all the regex experts out there! I'm trying to figure out how to group my url into parts using regular expressions.

Example:

```
site.com/user/account/info/settings
```

I want to be able to capture the `user/accout/info` url **NOT** `/settings`

Can anyone take this challenge and be kind enough to help me out? Thanks!

Comment: What are possible inputs - is it always "site.com/user/account/info/"?

Comment: No. The url can be others too. Like "site.com/foo/bar/baz/settings". ect..

Comment: Do you always want to remove the last element? Are parameters possible (like "?hgttg=true&everythiing=42")? Please provide a list of possible scenarios you want to cover and what excactely you want to extract ...

Comment: Yes. I would like to remove the last element. Example: `site.com/foo/bar/remove-me` `site.com/foo/bar/baz/remove-me-too` `site.com/foo/remove-me`

Comment: Actually, not really trying removing it. I'm trying to built a cms, where, `foo/bar/baz` is the uri which maps to a specific controller and `foo/bar/baz/settings` where `settings` is the controller action name. Also, `foo/bar/baz/settings/param1/param2` maps controller `settings` with parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the beginning of the URL try this:

```
(\/.*\/(?!.*\/.+))
```

Input:

> site.com/foo/remove-me/
>   site.com/user/account/info/settings
>   site.com/foo/bar/remove-me
>   site.com/foo/remove-me?param1=true&param2=hello+world

Output:

> /foo/
>   /user/account/info/
>   /foo/bar/
>   /foo/

https://regex101.com/r/yI5rG4/2

After consideration of all your comments under your post, I understand that you want to get the last segment for controller name extraction. Hence try this:

```
(?:\/(?!.*\/.+))([^\?\n]*)
```

Used on these inputs:

> site.com/foo/remove-me/
>   site.com/user/account/info/settings
>   site.com/foo/bar/remove-me
>   site.com/foo/remove-me?param1=true&param2=hello+world

Output for group 1:

> remove-me/
>   settings
>   remove-me
>   remove-me

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/kR5tX6/2

Comment: EXACTLY What I'm looking for! Thank you so much Markus!

Comment: The first one works perfectly! However, how do you remove the trailing slash both at the end and at the start? `/user/account/info/` to `user/account/info`

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Try this: `\/(.*)\/(?!.*\/.+)`

Comment: Yes! Works as expected. Thank you!